# get the values of all closest fields where the input checkbox is checked dynamically with serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I use `codeigniter` and `jquery` 
By example if `input#1` is checked, i have to get the value of `input#menu-1` 
if `input#2` is checked i get the value of `input#menu-2` ...
even if all are checked , 
what i tried :

```
<form id="form">
                    <h2 class="text-uppercase font-weight-light">votre choix : </h2>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="1">
                        <label for="menu-1">item 1<span class="font-weight-bold">($ 500 )</span> x
                        </label>
                        <input id="menu-1" type="number" class="min" maxlength="2" value="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="2">
                        <label for="menu-2">item 2<span class="font-weight-bold">(2500 FCFA)</span> x
                        </label>
                        <input id="menu-2" type="number" class="min" maxlength="2" value="0">
                    </div>
                    <button id="next-1" type="submit" class="btn border border-secondary p-2">COMMANDER</button>
                </form>
```

i have tried :

```
$('#next-1').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $("#form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url("index.php/user/process") ?>'
            method: 'POST',
            data: form,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (reponse) {

            }
        });
    });
```

my controller :

```
public function process()
    {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $data = $this->input->post();
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```

but i don't get values  so it doesn't work

Comment: where is `$('#next-2')` id in your from ?

Comment: it's rather #next-1 @SundarBan i just edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are missing name attribute in input. Try this

```
<input id="menu-1" type="number" class="min" maxlength="2" value="1" name="menu-1"> // check here name attribute at last.
```

form serialize take value from name attribute.

in your javascript

```
$("#form").click(function (e) {
        let form = $(this);
//for data filtering
var serializedReturn = form.find('input[name!=menu-1]').serialize(); // here menu-1 be removed.
        console.log(serializedReturn, 'value');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: I understand but possible to filter datas and take only values like in my example ? with jquery?

Comment: you can filter value by `var serializedReturn = $(this).find('input[name!=menu-1]').serialize(); `